# UITableViewController doesn't show content

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I try make some iPhone app and my UITableViewController doesn't show content. I mean title of cell for example. You can see at the picture bottom, that I designed table, but when I run this app, only top menu shows without content bottom.[image]

Comment: For a UITableViewController to work properly you must have implemented the following three methods. The last two are mandatory. numberOfSectionsInTableView:, tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:, tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. Have you written these into your TVC?

Comment: You need to assign valid datasource for the table view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check `delegate` and `datasource` method of `UITableView`, are you set it or not? If YES, then check `numberOfRowAtIndexPath` is it proper number of row ? if YES, then check `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ? set

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
```

Try with above suggestion, hope that its help for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

For this I think you have to check the datasource and delegate methods of table view. Their you have to give values for numberOfRows, numberOfSections,and then give text to your cell in cellForRowAtIndexpath method. Also don't forget to give reuseIdentifier to your cell in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the tableview datasource and delegate methods. Check image for information.

[image]

Also in the ViewController you need to use three methods:numberOfSectionsInTableView:, tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:,tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: